# Calculate with general discrete probability functions?

Tags: functions, probability-or-statistics

I would like to work with a discrete probability function $P[x\_]$ that only has the property that it is defined for $x\geq0$, such that

```
Sum[P[x],{x,0,Infinity}]
```

yields $1$.

How do I need to define $P[x\_]$?

Comment: Have a look at [ProbabilityDistribution](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProbabilityDistribution.html).

Comment: @b.gatessucks I have tried
    `Sum[ProbabilityDistribution[z, {x, 0, Infinity, 1}], {x, 0 
  Infinity}]`
without success: The sum does not converge

Comment: You have not defined what the PDF for the distribution is; replace `z` with it. There are examples at the page linked above.

Comment: @b.gatessucks I don‘t want to give more details. For each distribution function, no matter which one, the sum is one

Comment: The distribution has to make sense. You have defined a distribution which has a constant value over an infinite range; it is not normalizable.

Comment: @b.gatessucks ok, I see that. My original question remains, then, though. There are properties of probability functions that hold for ANY distribution. I want to utilize this and not narrow down myself to one specific distribution. Or is this not doable with Mathematica?

Comment: @IceFire What do you want to do with it, once you have it defined? Perhaps we could propose a different way of solving the underlying  problem if you tell us what your ultimate goal is.

Comment: @b.gatessucks I have a complex expression involving multiple pdf and cdf and would like to simplify it because, to be honest, doing this myself on paper has a high chance of me making mistakes

Comment: @IceFire I'd suggest, then, that you either amend this question to include that point and your actual expression or (perhaps better), ask a new question about that. Make sure to include your expression explicitly, in MMA format, with all definitions etc.